# Ora: 01036 illegal variable name/number in ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects, oracle-dbms, feature-class

I want to write a feature to a featureclass and use bellow code.On StopingEditing() return error  "Ora: 01036 illegal variable name/number
".

What am i missing?

```
            IWorkspace ws = SdeUtil.rtnWorkSpace();
            IFeatureClass reqFC = SdeUtil.getFeatureClassFromWs("SDE.Linecost_Dimand_Request", ws);
            IWorkspaceEdit2 wsEdit = ws as IWorkspaceEdit2;
            wsEdit.StartEditing(false);
            wsEdit.StartEditOperation();
            IFeature reqFeature = reqFC.CreateFeature();
            IPoint point = Session["requestPoint"] as IPoint;
            reqFeature.Shape = point;

            int fInd = reqFeature.Fields.FindField("COORDS");
            reqFeature.set_Value(fInd, string.Format("{0:f2};{1:f2}", point.X, point.Y));

            fInd = reqFeature.Fields.FindField("REQ_USER_NAME");
            reqFeature.set_Value(fInd, ClsShares.UserName);

            fInd = reqFeature.Fields.FindField("REQ_DATE");
            reqFeature.set_Value(fInd, DateTime.Now.Date);

            for (int i = 0; i < grid.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                DataControlField field = grid.Columns[i];
                BoundField bfield = field as BoundField;

                if (bfield == null)
                    continue;
                string fieldName = bfield.DataField;
                fInd = reqFeature.Fields.FindField(fieldName);
                if (fInd == -1)
                    continue;


                IField f = reqFeature.Fields.get_Field(fInd);
                esriFieldType ef = f.Type;
                double val;
                if (f.Type == esriFieldType.esriFieldTypeDouble)
                {
                    val = double.Parse(row.Cells[i].Text);

                    reqFeature.set_Value(fInd, val);
                }
                else
                {
                    reqFeature.set_Value(fInd, row.Cells[i].Text);
                }

            }

            reqFeature.Store();
            wsEdit.StopEditOperation();
            wsEdit.StopEditing(true);
```

Comment: In the future, please always include complete version descriptions of all software in use (Oracle to five places A.B.C.D.E, and ArcGIS to release, service pack, and patch level)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That was from service packs. You need to setup service packs

Comment: Does that solve the error?

Comment: Yes, That's work correctly.

Comment: In that case you can mark your own answer as the correct one. Just accept it with the little grey tick to the left of this post.